# Calling this inside nested object in array return undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call `this` inside a nested object in an array in node.js, but it's returning `undefined`.

```
var foo = {
    dog: 'max',
    cat: {
        names: [
            { grey: this.dog }
        ]
    }

};
```

When I try and do `foo.cat.names[0].grey` it returns `undefined`. I'm not in any functions, so I don't believe I have to cache `this`, right?

Comment: If you're not in any functions, `this` refers to the global object not the object you are constructing.  Since `global.dog` doesn't exist, you're setting the `grey` property to `undefined`.

Comment: What does this have to do with node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have pointed out, `this` doesn't exist in block scopes, only function scopes.

You will be better off defining your object in stages like this:

```
var foo = {};
foo.dog = 'max';
foo.cat = {
    names: [
        { grey: foo.dog }
    ]
}
```